# Russian Roulette command

Tags: bots, discord.js

I have a discord bot made with discord.js, and I've been trying to add a Russian roulette command to it for a while now. I want it to have a 1 in 6 chance of the gun "going off", and if that happens, I want the user to be muted for 30 seconds. The randomizer works, but for the life of me I can't get the bot to mute a user. I've tried looking at similar questions, but couldn't find anything helpful. Here's what I have so far. Be warned, I'm teaching myself js atm, so the code is super trashy. Thanks for any help!

```
var Command = require("../../plugins/Command System/command-system/command");

class russianCommand extends Command {
constructor(client, cs)
{
    super(client, {
        name: "russian",
        memberName: "russian",
        description: "Play a game of Russian Roulette"
    });

    this.cs = cs;
}

async load(msg, args)
{
    const userToMute = msg.author;

    const muteRole = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "Muted");

    const MUTE_TIME = 30 * 1000;

  const answer = [
    ' You\'re safe... For now...',
    ' You\'re safe... For now...',
    ' You\'re safe... For now...',
    ' You\'re safe... For now...',
    ' You\'re safe... For now...',
    ' You died.',
    ]

msg.channel.send(answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)]
)

if (answer === ' You died.')
    userToMute.addRole(muteRole);

    setTimeout(() => {
        msg.userToMute.removeRoles(muteRole);
    }, MUTE_TIME);

 }
}

module.exports = russianCommand;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `userToMute` should be member not user, a way u finding role is deprecated, you also using removeRole**s** instead of removeRole method, check discord.js docs https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole

```
let userToMute = msg.member;
let muteRole = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');
let muteTime = 30 * 1000;

let random = Math.random() * 100;
// console.log(random);
if (random < 100 / 6) {
  msg.channel.send(' You died.');
  userToMute.addRole(muteRole);
  setTimeout(() => userToMute.removeRole(muteRole), muteTime);
} else {
  msg.channel.send(' You\'re safe... For now...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.